# Flex how to display table of item that stay aligned vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flex-grow

I am working on a website, and this page is the one where I display all the orders the user have.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cedric_ublu/weyxmqc5/6/) Containing all the code.

```css
.flex {    
     display: flex;
}
.flex-i {
     color: white;
     background-color: blue;
     padding: 20px;
     flex-grow: 1;
     border: 5px solid red;
     text-align: center;
}
.flex-i:first-child {
     border-right: 0;
     flex-grow: 3;
}
.flex-i:last-child {
     border-left: 0;
     flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
     <div class="flex-i">#ord00000376sufdiwnfgw</div>
     <div class="flex-i">11:54:02, 03-12-2018l</div>
     <div class="flex-i">2824,89€</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
     <div class="flex-i">Just Normal</div>
     <div class="flex-i">Just Normal</div>
     <div class="flex-i">Just Normal</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
     <div class="flex-i">#ord00000372suf</div>
     <div class="flex-i">11:32:24, 03-12-2018</div>
     <div class="flex-i">24,71€</div>
</div>
```

So the problem I have it that I would like to display them all but vertically Align

I want for instance the `Price` Part to always have the same size, and all the column to have the same sizes to do not display badly as is it actually. BUT keep it mind that the first column `order number` must be bigger than the date for instance

Comment: I think you're going to have to give them all the same flex-basis. Why not put the data in a table?

Comment: the usual thing would be to give the money column a rem width to cover the largest amount you think is possible (or that someone will reasonably be able to spend), same with the date column and then just let the other column grow to fill the remainder, but as one of the answers says, this is tabular data so why not just use a table and then that will calculate cell widths based on their content and seems to be just what you are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by adding a minimum flex-basis to the main class it seems to look better

**EDIT**

note the use of `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
.flex {    
 display: flex;
position: relative;
}
.flex-i {
 color: white;
 background-color: blue;
 padding: 20px;
 flex-grow: 1;
 border: 5px solid red;
 text-align: center;
 flex-basis: 33%;
  
}
.flex-i:first-child {
 border-right: 0;
 flex-grow: 3;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 max-width: 25%;
 
}
.flex-i:last-child {
 border-left: 0;
 flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
     <div class="flex-i">#ord00000376sufdiwnfgw</div>
     <div class="flex-i">11:54:02, 03-12-2018l</div>
     <div class="flex-i">2824,89€</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
     <div class="flex-i">Just Normal</div>
     <div class="flex-i">Just Normal</div>
     <div class="flex-i">Just Normal</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
     <div class="flex-i">#ord00000372suf</div>
     <div class="flex-i">11:32:24, 03-12-2018</div>
     <div class="flex-i">24,71€</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the Idea is good but I have a problem, if I add a loooooonger name into any `order number` it breaks the vertical alignment

Comment: How it has to behave in that case? horizzontal scroll? overflow-hidden? text ellipsis?

Comment: Return to the line because the size must not change

Comment: I updated my answer, you can use `word-wrap: break-word;` and set a fixed width to leverage on Flex

Comment: Interesting thank you, I will try it online and give you feedback asap

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think you're using css flex for the wrong reasons here. It's better you use a table like so:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! The condition was to use flexbox so it does not suit my request, but I keep it in mind for the next times !